# can't find jQuery's $ on asus tablet with android 3.2

Tags: jquery, android, cordova

I wanted to test an app which I developed against API level 7 on our Asus tablet. Probably it won't look to nice or anything but I'd just like to see how it looks like. As external libraries we use jQuery, jQ mobile and Phonegap.

However the app won't even start:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $ at file:///android_asset/www/main.js:7
```

which is the following line:

```
$(function(event){//waiting for document
```

I'm totally blasted by this also because the app actually works on my 2.2 droid without any changes in the code. I appreciate any information related to this issue. :C

Comment: You need to show how and where you embed jQuery

Comment: Have you tried using `jQuery.noConflict();` and using `jQuery()` instead of `$()`?

Comment: Does logcat show an error loading the jquery source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the platform does not like to include external scripts like

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

I had already downloaded the libraries and changing the source attribute to the local copy solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace '$' with 'JQuery' :)

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: JQuery is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/main.js:7 :) please notice the code works on a 2.2 system!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before. Most off the time a different library is imported (like prototype) . Simply replace the '$' for 'jQuery' see:

http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Comment: Nope as stated I haven't changed the code at all and it works on 2.2 droid.

Comment: Don't waste your time to must with looking at the working code on Android 2.2 Maybe you call main.js earlier than jquery.js? Maybe you can add more of you code implementation in your original questions? Do you use(import) Jquery core and jquery mobile at the same time? This can also causes the problem. When you use the slider for example...