# PhoneGap (Cordova.js) and JQuery.Ajax not working together

Tags: jquery, cordova

I have built a html page using Phonegap+Jquery targeting Andriod 4.12.

My business requirement is to take a picture using the camera API of cordova.js and then post this captured picture to a ASMX web service.

Problem : When I add a reference to Cordova.js and run the application I get an error in the LogCat "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" but if i remove the reference to cordova.js everything works fine and i am able to post data to web service.

I am attaching my code for reference.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>    
<title>Capture Photo</title>   
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">

 var varType;
 var varUrl;
 var varData;
 var varContentType;
 var varDataType;
 var varProcessData;

  function InsertDetails() {
        alert('Inserting Details');
        varType = "POST";
        varUrl = "http://mobile.comp.com/service/userservice.asmx/InsertDetails";
        varContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        varDataType = "json";
        varProcessData = true;

        var uname = document.getElementById('txtname');
        var pwd = document.getElementById('txtpwd');
        CallService(uname.value, pwd.value);

        return true;
    }

    //Generic function to call AXMX/WCF  Service        
    function CallService(u, p) {
        $.ajax({ type: varType, url: varUrl, data: '{"username":"' + u + '","password":"' + p + '"}', contentType: varContentType, dataType: varDataType, processdata: varProcessData, success: function (msg) { ServiceSucceeded(msg); }, error: ServiceFailed });
    }

    function ServiceSucceeded(result) {

        var myObject = eval('(' + result.d + ')');
        alert(myObject);
    }
    function ServiceFailed(result) {
        alert('Service call failed: ' + result.status + '' + result.statusText);
        varType = null; varUrl = null; varData = null; varContentType = null; varDataType = null; varProcessData = null;
    } 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type=text id=txtname value=John />
<input type=text id=txtpwd value=Doe /> 
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" onclick="InsertDetails();" style="cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 8px; vertical-align: top" value="Insert Details" />

     <button id=btn1>Capture Photo</button> 

</body>
</html>
```

Please help me out in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Nick for your help. The 3rd link helped

Finally my code worked

I added the following line of code which did the magic for me.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

JQuery was recognised after that. Make sure to follow the proper sequence for javascripts else the code will not work.

The sequence in which I referred the js files:

1. Reference to  JQuery.js (locally added to project)
2. jQuery.noConflict();
3. Javascript Code for service calls
4. Reference to Cordova.js
5. Cordova Camera interaction code

Answer (score 3):

Doing some searches for similar problems shows a few possible answers.

1) Load jQuery locally instead of from the CDN. You already seem to be doing this but I'll mention it for others with similar problems.

[can't find jQuery's $ on asus tablet with android 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487657/cant-find-jquerys-on-asus-tablet-with-android-3-2)

2) Tell jQuery to allow Cross Domain requests. Look at the sections '$.support.cors' and '$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages' in the link below.

https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/pages/phonegap.html

3) Tell jQuery to play nice. It might be that cordova.js is using another JS library that wants to use $ as well. Since you're loading cordova first the other JS library is claimingg $ before jQuery can.

http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries