# Jquery-jsonp gives "error" on Android, but not in desktop browser

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jsonp

I'm having this problem with the combination of jQueryMobile (which includes jQuery) and jquery.jsonp, a special library for jsonp calls.

[This](https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp) is the git repository for the jquery.jsonp library. It was a while back that I made the decision to use this special library instead of using $.ajax with the `datatype:"jsonp"` option, so I don't remember exactly why, except it was or seemed to be necessary.

I've already looked around and followed the advice in [this related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469959/phonegap-cordova-js-and-jquery-ajax-not-working-together): 
(1) I load all js and other files locally
(2) $.support.cors and $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages are set to true
(3) there is no conflict around the $ variable claimed by jQuery

**The code**

So there must be something different going on. This is my code...

```
$.jsonp({
    data: allData,
    url: 'https://www.ssl-id.net/afford-it.me/functions/spendable2.php',
    cache: false,
    timeout: 6000,
    callbackParameter: "callback",
    success: function(returned,status){ ... },
    error: function(repeatedOptions,status){...},
    complete: function(repeatedOptions,status){...},
};
```

**The error**

When the app fires this jsonp command, the error event triggers (as well as the complete event) and the status it gives is "error". That could also have been timeout, according to the [docs](https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp/blob/master/doc/API.md#error---function-undefined).
Also, in the console, is an "unknown chromium error: 0"

**Differential diagnosis**

There is no problem when I run the app in the desktop browser: it only happens on Android.
[This guy](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jqm-jsonp-works-in-local-browser-with-phonegap-android-the-server-gets-the-request-but-nothing-shows-up-in-listview) had a great explanation (Android balks at any missing closing tags in the html, and this only causes problems when doing cross-domain calls) but it didn't help me.

Can anyone figure out what is wrong here? I'll gladly provide more data if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out thanks to [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18325393/phonegap-android-webview-throws-unknown-chromium-error-0) on Stackoverflow. It's about access origin. And it's not Android getting in the way, but Phonegap.

Phonegap does not allow cross-domain unless you specify the domain name in the config.xml file.

To be precise, put it in the config.xml file in the [myProject]/www folder, or it will be overwritten at next build. This is the [Phonegap documentation on whitelisting](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide).